# Wix 3.10 not adding application to Add/Remove Programs

Tags: wix, upgrade, wix3.9, wix3.10

I recently switched from using Wix 3.9 to Wix 3.10 in order to use Wix in visual studio 2015 and I noticed that in Wix 3.10 (without adding code changes), it is not adding my installer application to the Add/Remove Programs anymore. However if i build my installer using Wix 3.9 it works to add to Add/Remove programs. Has anyone seen this issue? Is there a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make the verbose logging enabled and check if there is an error while the 3.10 version installer runs? The command line you can use to get a verbose log is 'msiexec /i <your msi> /l!*vx <logname>'.

Comment: I have several msi packages in my installer. But I ran verbose logging on all of them. While all of them end with "Installation completed successfully".   I do see these two error codes:1707 and 1709.  What do these mean?  If i change to compile the msi's with version 3.9, my installer's executable is back in add/remove programs.

Comment: I did a search for error codes 1707 ad 1709 and these seem to be success values so other than that there are no other errors found in the logs.

Comment: From the logs i don't see any other errors. The only difference between 3.9 and 3.10 is that in 3.10 it had created the uninstall registry entry for my bootstrapper .exe application in  SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ but then at the end of install it removed this registry entry calling Removed bundle dependency provider. This did not happen in 3.9.